# Converting a group of Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) into Web Font Format, aka a WOFF font

Tags: fonts, conversion, svg

I am looking for a way to **`SVG`** graphics into a **`WOFF`** font. A software solution would be ideal for the use case, though I would welcome a programatic solution if the lib/api/module (whatever it is) is robust enough. There is a module I have been using, but it cuases a million NPM errors, and sometimes I get an error in a conversion, but when I run it again it works. The module is for Node.js, and isn't maintained, I was hoping to find somthing a little more reliable. As I stated, a software solution would be best, as I need to only do a 1 time conversion, but I need to do it several times. In other words, I am not writing a program that needs the ability to convert the images into a font, but I am writing an extension for VS Code, and during the development process I may need to update the WOFF font several times. Once the extension is finished though, it just needs the WOFF font, not the ability to convert from SVG to WOFF.

- ###### My OS is: `Fedora 36: Workstation x64`

any ideas?

Comment: To be honest, a library might work, if its for C or C++.

Answer (score -2):

If there are tools available then hand the files to them with a `for in do` or `find --exec {}\`